# Euro/currency sign after amount in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I want to move the euro/currency symbol in the sugarcrm quotes pdf's.
It is actually before the amount, but it has to be printed out after the amount.

Is it possible?

Example:

€4444 <- wrong

4444€ <- correct

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this page:
   http://www.evertype.com/standards/euro/formats.html

it seems that €4444 format is the correct one for Italy.

But the way I come to your post looking for the same issue.

Regards.